# Cannot fetch data with hasMany eloquent relationship?

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I'm trying to learn eloquent relationships. My relation is something like:
Users hasMany posts and a post belongs to a user.

**when I run my queries in tinker it shows errors.**

```
$user->new User();
$user->all(); //Displays all the users
but i cannot do
$user->all()->posts;
```

**it returns an empty array**
**but If I do something like:**

```
$posts = new Post();
$posts->all();
$post->users;
```

***Error: Exception with message 'Property [post] does not exist on this collection instance.'***

How can I achieve something like I want to have the users associated with posts or precisely I want users who have written posts.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the code you write the new User is missing a parenthencies.
It should be like this

```
$user = new User();// Initialize the user model class
$user->all(); //get all users
$userpost =  $user->posts // link the user model to the post
```

Try these it will resolve the error.

Comment: Ok. I guess the issues may laid in your User relationship. Laravel have  a way of relating model which you can get the  documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$usersWithPosts = User::has('posts')->get();
```